# Shopify Image Source from Files

Tags: image, shopify

How do i reference an image on my .liquid page from Files? I've tried {{ 'pin.png' | asset_url | img_tag }} which returns img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0930/7298/t/3/assets/pin.png?15115092952342036334" alt="" which is a broken image link for me.

Any ideas?

Comment: why is it a broken image link? did you try to append the http before the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up copying the source from the file

Comment: Copying the source can work aok. Keep in mind that if the file is every replaced with a new version it's possible that direct link won't show the latest version from the CDN.

Answer (score 2):

The correct filter to use for file urls (not asset urls) is **file_url**.
Take note of the [documentation](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/url-filters#file_url) for more info. For your example you'd be looking for something more like so:

```
{{ 'pin.png' | file_url | img_tag  }}
```